# Reinstalling assemblies for new user after reboot, why?

Tags: windows-installer, gac, installshield, installscript

I have Installshield InstallScript MSI aka "Full" setup and Installshield Basic MSI aka "Patch" setup.

Full setup copies some files to GAC, some to folder, etc.

Patch setup replaces some files in GAC and some in installation folder. How ingenious, isn't it? :)

Also, patch setup is designed that none of its actions are visible after installation. I'm changing some properties in sequences for that(damn, can't remember which ones, will look it up).

When patch is applied, application works well(administrator user), but when rebooting a computer and logging in as a different (just domain, not admin) user, application doesn't work.

In trace I have found an error line stating that installation of one of the components(to be precise, component which puts files to GAC) failed. Says that there is no installation source for it...

Why is this so? Setup is set to install for everyone, patch is just replacing some files, why does it need to "install" something when a new user logs in?

Thanks,
Marko

Comment: Here are warnings and error messages:
1. Detection of product '{GUID}', feature 'FeatureName', component '{COMPONENT_GUID}' failed.  The resource '' does not exist.

2. "ProductName" -- Error 1706.No valid source could be found for product "ProductName".  The Windows Installer cannot continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem... quite simple now that I've done it ...

I added a property in Property Manager in patch setup...

property name = ALLUSERS
property value = 1

Also, this link helped a lot [Installing an Application for All Users on Windows](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=Q105063&sliceId=#options)

Cheers, 
Marko